# JsonParseException: Fail to Deserializer JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the below exception when trying to deserialize this JSON string:

```
{ "studentName": "John", "studentAge": "20" }
```

Exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@41d241d2 failed to deserialize json object { "studentName": "John", "studentAge": "20" } given the type java.util.List<...>
    at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.deserialize(JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.java:64)
    at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.invokeCustomDeserializer(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:92)
```

These are my classes:

```
public class School {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = ...// I can read json from text file, the string is like { "className": "Math", "classTime": "2013-01-01 11:00", "studentList": { "studentName": "John", "studentAge": "20" }}
    CourseInfo bean = gson.fromJson(json,  CourseInfo.class);
}
```

CourseInfo.java:

```
public class CourseInfo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String className;
    private Timestamp classTime;
    private List<StudentInfo> studentList;

    ...
}
```

StudentInfo.java

```
public class CourseInfo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String studentName;
    private String studentAge;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to read some JSON which does not correspond to the object you are trying to read it into. Specifically, the `studentList` value in the JSON is an object:

```
{
    "studentName": "John",
    "studentAge": "20"
}
```

However, you are attempting to read that object into a list. Given that the variable is named `studentList`, I would guess that the JSON is wrong, not your code, and that it should be an array, instead:

```
{
    "className": "Math",
    "classTime": "2013-01-01 11:00",
    "studentList": [
        {
            "studentName": "John",
            "studentAge": "20"
        }
    ]
}
```